# Open Search: problems with Cognito not sending proper CORS headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-cognito, http-status-code-403, opensearch

In us-east-1 region we have a managed Open Search cluster. We have created this cluster with Fine-grained access control enabled and for the master user we have selected Internal user data base. We have enabled Cognito, with this configuration:

User pool
Identity pool
IAM role name

We have a problem with Cognito. We can create new users from AWS Cognito console and later use them to log in into the Open Search cluster. We can see Open Search indexes and run queries over the indexes. But we experience some weird behavior.

After having logged in using user and password, we can navigate normally OpenSearch (e.g. query our indexes or look at our dashboards). But then, after some X amount of seconds/minutes, we start seeing some pop ups in the down right corner showing a "forbidden" message, and if we open the Developer Console we can see a lot of CORS issues. These CORS issues are coming from Cognito API calls that Open Search is doing from the web site. The CORS issues are due to Cognito as it doesn't return the Allowed Origins header. There is nothing in the documentation about CORS, Cognito and Open Search. This happens in any browser. Sometimes the mentioned pop up doesn't even appear, but the page stays blank and it doesn't show anything. The message from the browser console is very clear:

(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403

This prevents me from using the Open Search cluster normally. One would think that this is a bug in Cognito as it is not allowing API calls from the Open Search domain.

Any help is welcome.

EDIT:

[developer console CORS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUbdl.png)

[forbidden error from Open Search website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psXED.jpg)

Comment: Any screenshots?

Comment: Just added them. Thanks!

Comment: It may be a bug - I would advise you to create an AWS support case or post on AWS re:Post to grab the attention of the relevant teams.

Comment: I just did https://repost.aws/questions/QU-H9vwxQQT4W6T46hQx40og/open-search-problems-with-cognito-not-sending-proper-cors-headers